# Jsonpath for length of array

Tags: arrays, groovy, size, spock, jsonpath

Given json such as

```
{"arr1" : [1,2,3], "arr2" : []}
```

where it is known that there are arrays named arr1 and arr2, is there a jsonpath expression for the *length* of an array that will work for both empty and non-empty arrays?

I have made several attempts using google code's JsonPath library, of note:

```
JsonPath.read(json, "arr1.length")
```

but it gives an error saying that arrays have no attributes.

I am looking for a single string path that resolves to an array's length, not a subsequent call to an intermediate, eg

```
JsonPath.read(json, "arr1").length // useless to me
```

Any level of complexity of expression is acceptable.

For context, I want to feed a test suit with path/value pairs, which works great for values, but I can't assert array *size* with this pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the length of an array is required only for assertion then `json-path-assert` artifact can be used in conjunction with `JsonPath`. Here is a sample written in Groovy:

```
@Grab('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.9.1')
@Grab('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.9.1')

import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath
import static com.jayway.jsonassert.JsonAssert.*
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*

def json = /{ "arr1": [1,2,3], "arr2": [] }/

with(json).assertThat( "arr1", hasSize(3) )
          .assertThat( "arr2", hasSize(0) )
          .assertThat( "arr2", emptyCollection() )
```

Verify that assertion fails with different size of array. Best part is the use of [Hamcrest's Matcher API](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) which opens door to flexible and wide variety of assertions.

Length cannot be obtained from the path expression AFAIK.

Comment: FYI, I used the tabular data format of `where:` and passed in to the test a path and a `Matcher`, eg `"arr2" | hasSize(0)` and in the test `with(json).assertThat(path, expected)`

Comment: That will be the best use of data driven specs and `Matchers`. :) I like that way.

Answer (score 1):

@dmahapatro is right stating that

> Length cannot be obtained from the path expression

**But** if you only need it to access some specific element (let's say the last element of an array), you could still use :

```
{"arr1": [1,2,3], "arr2": [{"name": "a"}, {"name": "b"}]}
arr1[(@.length-1)]       // returns "3"
arr2[(@.length-1)].name  // returns "b"
```

You can also do more advanced requests, but for that i suggest you take a look at the plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath).

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying with Java Rest Assure  then one way is use .getList("arr1").size() method.

My pom.xml has below rest assure dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


    @Test
public void getArrayLength() {
    String input = "{\"arr1\" : [1,2,3], \"arr2\" : []}";
    JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.from(input);
    System.out.println(jsonPath.getList("arr1").size());
}
```

[image]